# HTTPS python request authentication failed

Tags: python, python-requests

Using requests I am trying to access https connection. The basic auth is not working.

I installed

```
pip install requests[security]
```

but no luck. Tried download the certificate from following command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <host>:<port>  </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem
```

and trying following code Getting error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

Here is my code

```
import requests  
s = requests.Session()  
requests.get(url , verify='/path/to/certfile')  
s.verify =cert_path  
s.auth = (usr, pwd)  
resp = s.get(url).content
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)

Comment: Are you sure that your "path to certfile" is properly pointing to the pem file you have saved?